# Why won't SpringBoot simultaneously display HTML on localhost and connect to mysql datasource?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, web, raspberry-pi, mariadb

I wrote a small spring boot project with a Mustache page with basic inputs and text displayed in response to submitting text inputs. Then I set up a Raspberrypi with Mariadb server. Once I set up the application.props file to connect to the pi (using specifically the IP address), it would no longer load the mustache page and instead shows 404 error on localhost.

My goal is to have the view from mustache be able to change based on what's stored in the mariadb datasource. Additions to the page will be stored in DB and eventually other users can access those thru the DB. Instead, they do not work in tandem, as a connection to mariadb leads to a 404 error on the localhost page. Do I need a separate microservice for displaying the views or is localhost the wrong option at this point in testing?